# Java Program taking So much Long

Tags: java

I am trying to solve this [Question](https://projecteuler.net/problem=601)

> Question :
>
> For every positive number nn we define the function
>   streak(n)=kstreak(n)=k as the smallest positive integer k such that
>   n+k is not divisible by k+1. E.g: 13 is divisible by 1  14 is
>   divisible by 2  15 is divisible by 3  16 is divisible by 4  17 is NOT
>   divisible by 5  So streak(13)=4.  Similarly: 120 is divisible by 1 
>   121 is NOT divisible by 2  So streak(120)=1.
>
> Define P(s,N) to be the number of integers nn, 1
>
> Find the sum, as ii ranges from 1 to 31, of P(i,4^{i}).

This code is taking a very long time to finish. What are the possible ways to reduce the time that it takes?

My code is as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static long streak(long n){

        if(n%2 == 0){
            return 1l;
        }

        long count=0;
        for (int i=1;i<1000;i++){
            if (n%i==0){
                n++;
            }else {
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static long function (long s, long N){
        long count=0;
        for (long n=2;n<N;n++){
            if(streak(n) == s)
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum=0;
        System.out.println("Streak of 13 = "+streak(13));
        System.out.println("Streak of 120 = "+streak(120));
        System.out.println("P(6,1000000)= "+function(6,1000000));
        long powVal = 0l;
        long n = 0l;
        for (long i=1;i<32;i++){
            powVal = (long) Math.pow(4,i);

            for (n = 2; n < powVal; n++){
                if(streak(n) == i)
                    sum++;
            }

            long funcRet = function(i, powVal);
            sum+= funcRet;
            System.out.println("P("+i+","+powVal+") = " + funcRet);
            System.out.println("SUM : " +sum);

//              System.out.println("SUM for " + i + " = " +sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "very long time." How long does it take now, and how long do you think that it *should* take instead?

Comment: You're doing over 500 million operations just in the first 3 lines of `main`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited for Code Review SE!

Comment: @EJoshuaS  Not ending

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh The problem is the sheer number of operations you're performing (see my answer below).

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I disagree because he's asking about a specific problem with it, and broken code belongs here rather than on Code Review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the sheer number of operations you're doing. As I indicated in the comments, you're doing over 500 million operations in the first 3 lines of `main` alone.

I also used trace statements to find out how many operations you were performing in the second half of this (I dumbly named the total number of operations `s`):

```
long s = 1;
        for (long i = 1; i < 32; i++)
        {
            s = 1;
            long powVal = (long)Math.Pow(4, i);

            Trace.TraceInformation("powVal: " + powVal);

            for (int n = 2; n < powVal; n++)
            {
                // Each call to streak could entail 1000 operations
                s *= 1000;
                Trace.TraceInformation("s: " + s.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Here are partial results:

```
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : powVal: 4
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 1000
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 1000000
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : powVal: 16
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 1000
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 1000000
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 1000000000
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 1000000000000
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 1000000000000000
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 1000000000000000000
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 3875820019684212736
VB Parser.vshost.exe Information: 0 : s: 2003764205206896640
```

And that's only a partial result. As you can see, you're doing an *astronomical* number of calculations. You need to reduce that in order to make the performance manageable.

Comment: Thanks For helping

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh Happy to help

Comment: I upvoted it but it didnt shows as i have less reputation

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh Thanks

Comment: Can u tell me why there is -5 before my question?

Comment: @RishabhDeepSingh I'm not sure, actually, it seems like a reasonable question to me.